# react-async-script implementation: wrapping a component

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-async

I am trying to wrap a react component that requires the google maps api, with a `makeAsyncScriptLoader` from `react-async-script`.

In the same file (if that makes a difference):

```
class SearchBar extends Component {
    /* Some stuff requiring the maps api */
}

const callbackName = "onloadcallback";
const URL = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDSn_vNbNZzrcFxl8bV3MH1j0kuoLVsOCQ&callback=${callbackName}`;
const globalName = "foo";

export default makeAsyncScriptLoader(URL, {
  callbackName: callbackName,
  globalName: globalName
})(SearchBar);
```

My understanding, is that I should then be able to call the component from another file by importing `SearchBarWrapper` from the above file, and using it as `<SearchBarWrapper />`.

Basically, it doesn't work. The component tries to load without the script, and fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://github.com/dozoisch/react-async-script) the following properties could be specified to ensure JavaScript resource is  finished loading:

> `asyncScriptOnLoad`: function : called after script finishes loading.
>   using script.onload

or

> `callbackName`: string : If the script needs to call a global function
>   when finished loading (for example:
>   recaptcha/api.js?onload=callbackName). Please provide the callback
>   name here and it will be autoregistered on window for you.

For the case of `asyncScriptOnLoad` event the following [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) could be introduced to ensure a wrapped component is rendered once JavaScript resource is loaded:

```
function withScript(url, WrappedComponent) {

  const LoadingElement = props =>  {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  class Wrapper extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        scriptLoaded: false
      };
    }
    render() {
      const AsyncScriptLoader = makeAsyncScriptLoader(url)(LoadingElement);
      if(this.state.scriptLoaded){
         return <WrappedComponent/>
      } 
      return (
        <AsyncScriptLoader
          asyncScriptOnLoad={() => {
            this.setState({scriptLoaded: true});
          }}
        />
      );
    }
  }
  return Wrapper;
}
```

Now Google Maps component could be rendered like this:

```
const GoogleMapsUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyDurZQBXjtSzKeieXwtFeGe-jhZu-HEGQU`;
const App = withScript(GoogleMapsUrl, Autocomplete);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/4jn6mxlww9)